# Lyx freeze with external monitor in MacOS

Tags: lyx

Lyx freezes every time when I disconnect and sometimes connect an external monitor.  Anyone else have this problem and have solution? Thank you.
This is part of the stack trace:

Date/Time:       2016-09-20 07:37:36 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.11.6 (Build 15G31)
Architecture:    x86_64h
Report Version:  22

Command:         LyX
Path:            /Applications/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/lyx
Version:         2.2.1 (???)
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             18368

Event:           hang
Duration:        4.00s (process was unresponsive for 197 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           40 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  MacBookPro11,4
Active cpus:     8

Fan speed:       2155 rpm

---

Timeline format: stacks are sorted chronologically

### Use -i and -heavy to re-report with count sorting

Heaviest stack for the main thread of the target process:
  40  start + 52 (lyx + 6244) [0x106439864]
  40  main + 67 (lyx + 6319) [0x1064398af]
  40  lyx::LyX::exec(int&, char**) + 898 (lyx + 1109106) [0x106546c72]
  40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1976197) [0x107942785]
  40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1959105) [0x10793e4c1]
  40  ??? (<1EEFEE86-01D7-376A-9216-2BE14E0C1544> + 140159) [0x10b73537f]
  40  -[NSApplication run] + 682 (AppKit + 249216) [0x7fff91666d80]
  40  -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454 (AppKit + 295462) [0x7fff91672226]
  40  _DPSNextEvent + 1067 (AppKit + 298486) [0x7fff91672df6]
  40  _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71 (HIToolbox + 198063) [0x7fff8e1255af]
  40  ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184 (HIToolbox + 198263) [0x7fff8e125677]
  40  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235 (HIToolbox + 198965) [0x7fff8e125935]
  40  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296 (CoreFoundation + 560856) [0x7fff8a3e1ed8]
  40  **CFRunLoopRun + 927 (CoreFoundation + 562399) [0x7fff8a3e24df]
  40  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556 (CoreFoundation + 565180) [0x7fff8a3e2fbc]
  40  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17 (CoreFoundation + 698497) [0x7fff8a403881]
  40  ??? (<1EEFEE86-01D7-376A-9216-2BE14E0C1544> + 144513) [0x10b736481]
  40  ??? (<1EEFEE86-01D7-376A-9216-2BE14E0C1544> + 142254) [0x10b735bae]
  40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1977652) [0x107942d34]
  40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1974548) [0x107942114]
  40  lyx::frontend::GuiApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 934 (lyx + 3714418) [0x1067c2d72]
  40  lyx::frontend::Alert::error(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, bool) + 149 (lyx + 3646254) [0x1067b232e]
  40  lyx::frontend::Alert::doError(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, bool) + 604 (lyx + 3645311) [0x1067b1f7f]
  40  non-virtual thunk to lyx::frontend::GuiProgress::error(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&) + 68 (lyx + 5090350) [0x106912c2e]
  40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 2183901) [0x1079752dd]
  40  lyx::frontend::GuiProgress::doError(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&) + 101 (lyx + 5087309) [0x10691204d]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2105164) [0x107ff4f4c]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2107453) [0x107ff583d]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 325436) [0x107e4273c]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 322793) [0x107e41ce9]
  40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1974548) [0x107942114]
  40  lyx::frontend::GuiApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 22 (lyx + 3713506) [0x1067c29e2]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 78896) [0x107e06430]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 68326) [0x107e03ae6]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2277045) [0x10801eeb5]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 328264) [0x107e43248]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2278942) [0x10801f61e]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2109148) [0x107ff5edc]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2109483) [0x107ff602b]
  40  ??? [0x404a000000000000]
  40  _sigtramp + 26 (libsystem_platform.dylib + 9514) [0x7fff84aa752a]
  40  lyx::error_handler(int) + 506 (lyx + 1126630) [0x10654b0e6]
  40  lyx::frontend::Alert::error(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, bool) + 149 (lyx + 3646254) [0x1067b232e]
  40  lyx::frontend::Alert::doError(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, bool) + 604 (lyx + 3645311) [0x1067b1f7f]
  40  non-virtual thunk to lyx::frontend::GuiProgress::error(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&) + 68 (lyx + 5090350) [0x106912c2e]
  40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 2183901) [0x1079752dd]
  40  lyx::frontend::GuiProgress::doError(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&) + 101 (lyx + 5087309) [0x10691204d]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2105164) [0x107ff4f4c]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2107453) [0x107ff583d]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 325436) [0x107e4273c]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 322793) [0x107e41ce9]
  40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1974548) [0x107942114]
  40  lyx::frontend::GuiApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 22 (lyx + 3713506) [0x1067c29e2]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 78896) [0x107e06430]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 68326) [0x107e03ae6]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2277045) [0x10801eeb5]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 328264) [0x107e43248]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2278942) [0x10801f61e]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2109148) [0x107ff5edc]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2109483) [0x107ff602b]
  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 58888) [0x107e01608]
 *39  hndl_alltraps + 229 (kernel + 2016373) [0xffffff80003ec475]
 *36  user_trap + 1090 (kernel + 1895906) [0xffffff80003cede2]
 *35  exception_triage + 496 (kernel + 901024) [0xffffff80002dbfa0]
 *32  mach_exception_raise + 139 (kernel + 1206907) [0xffffff8000326a7b]
 *23  mach_msg_rpc_from_kernel_body + 272 (kernel + 915744) [0xffffff80002df920]
 *22  ipc_mqueue_receive + 74 (kernel + 812938) [0xffffff80002c678a]
 *15  thread_block_reason + 175 (kernel + 986671) [0xffffff80002f0e2f]
 *15  ??? (kernel + 1000220) [0xffffff80002f431c]
 *12  machine_switch_context + 316 (kernel + 1875900) [0xffffff80003c9fbc]

Process:         lyx (LyX) [18368]
Path:            /Applications/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/lyx
Architecture:    x86_64
Parent:          launchd [1]
UID:             579674406
Task size:       171021 pages (+5)
CPU Time:        2.224s
Note:            Unresponsive for 197 seconds before sampling
Note:            2 idle work queue threads omitted

Thread 0x1efe6          DispatchQueue 1         40 samples (1-40)       priority 46-47 (base 46-47)                     cpu time 2.222s
  
  40  start + 52 (lyx + 6244) [0x106439864] 1-40
    40  main + 67 (lyx + 6319) [0x1064398af] 1-40
      40  lyx::LyX::exec(int&, char**) + 898 (lyx + 1109106) [0x106546c72] 1-40
        40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1976197) [0x107942785] 1-40
          40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1959105) [0x10793e4c1] 1-40
            40  ??? (<1EEFEE86-01D7-376A-9216-2BE14E0C1544> + 140159) [0x10b73537f] 1-40
              40  -[NSApplication run] + 682 (AppKit + 249216) [0x7fff91666d80] 1-40
                40  -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454 (AppKit + 295462) [0x7fff91672226] 1-40
                  40  _DPSNextEvent + 1067 (AppKit + 298486) [0x7fff91672df6] 1-40
                    40  _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71 (HIToolbox + 198063) [0x7fff8e1255af] 1-40
                      40  ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184 (HIToolbox + 198263) [0x7fff8e125677] 1-40
                        40  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235 (HIToolbox + 198965) [0x7fff8e125935] 1-40
                          40  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296 (CoreFoundation + 560856) [0x7fff8a3e1ed8] 1-40
                            40  **CFRunLoopRun + 927 (CoreFoundation + 562399) [0x7fff8a3e24df] 1-40
                              40  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556 (CoreFoundation + 565180) [0x7fff8a3e2fbc] 1-40
                                40  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17 (CoreFoundation + 698497) [0x7fff8a403881] 1-40
                                  40  ??? (<1EEFEE86-01D7-376A-9216-2BE14E0C1544> + 144513) [0x10b736481] 1-40
                                    40  ??? (<1EEFEE86-01D7-376A-9216-2BE14E0C1544> + 142254) [0x10b735bae] 1-40
                                      40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1977652) [0x107942d34] 1-40
                                        40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1974548) [0x107942114] 1-40
                                          40  lyx::frontend::GuiApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 934 (lyx + 3714418) [0x1067c2d72] 1-40
                                            40  lyx::frontend::Alert::error(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, bool) + 149 (lyx + 3646254) [0x1067b232e] 1-40
                                              40  lyx::frontend::Alert::doError(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, bool) + 604 (lyx + 3645311) [0x1067b1f7f] 1-40
                                                40  non-virtual thunk to lyx::frontend::GuiProgress::error(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&) + 68 (lyx + 5090350) [0x106912c2e] 1-40
                                                  40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 2183901) [0x1079752dd] 1-40
                                                    40  lyx::frontend::GuiProgress::doError(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&) + 101 (lyx + 5087309) [0x10691204d] 1-40
                                                      40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2105164) [0x107ff4f4c] 1-40
                                                        40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2107453) [0x107ff583d] 1-40
                                                          40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 325436) [0x107e4273c] 1-40
                                                            40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 322793) [0x107e41ce9] 1-40
                                                              40  ??? (<732E2C80-7742-3F00-A709-E2337F03A2A1> + 1974548) [0x107942114] 1-40
                                                                40  lyx::frontend::GuiApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 22 (lyx + 3713506) [0x1067c29e2] 1-40
                                                                  40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 78896) [0x107e06430] 1-40
                                                                    40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 68326) [0x107e03ae6] 1-40
                                                                      40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2277045) [0x10801eeb5] 1-40
                                                                        40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 328264) [0x107e43248] 1-40
                                                                          40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2278942) [0x10801f61e] 1-40
                                                                            40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2109148) [0x107ff5edc] 1-40
                                                                              40  ??? (<5F42D60B-DD16-3E9E-BD80-9CD8D96FAC15> + 2109483) [0x107ff602b] 1-40
                                                                                40  ??? [0x404a000000000000] 1-40
                                                                                  40  _sigtramp + 26 (libsystem_platform.dylib + 9514) [0x7fff84aa752a] 1-40
                                                                                    40  lyx::error_handler(int) + 506 (lyx + 1126630) [0x10654b0e6] 1-40
                                                                                      40  lyx::frontend::Alert::error(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, bool) + 149 (lyx + 3646254) [0x1067b232e] 1-40

Comment: You might have better luck asking this at a LyX mailing list. Or reporting this as a bug with the LyX developers.

Comment: Yes, please post this information at http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome, formatting it using https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiFormatting#PreformattedText to ensure that it is readable.